# Achieving MasterData deduplication on Azure

Tags: azure, duplicates, master-data-management, data-quality-services, record-linkage

I am looking at achieving Master Data deduplication based on match percentages in AzureDB...was looking at something equivalent to Master Data Services/ DQS (Data Quality Services) in SQL Server2012

https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/SQL11UPD05-REC-06

Broadly looking for controls on match rules (exact, close match etc), handle dependencies and audit trail(undo capability etc)

I reckon this must be available in Azure cloud, if this is made available in SQL Server. Could you pls point me to how I get this done on AzureDB

Please note- I am NOT looking for data Sources like MelissaDAta, D&B that are listed on the Azure marketplace

Comment: Looking for the same thing, did you find a solution in Azure ?

Answer (score 0):

Master Data Services is not just a database process: it also centrally involves a website component, which still (as of 2021) requires some Windows server running IIS.

This can be an Azure Virtual Machine ([link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/master-data-services-installation-and-configuration?view=sql-server-ver15#-on-an-azure-virtual-machine)) but there is no serverless offering for this at this time.

The database itself can be hosted on an Azure SQL Managed Instance ([link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/master-data-services-host-database-on-managed-instance?view=sql-server-ver15)) but not on a standalone Azure SQL DB, as far as I can tell. This is presumably because some of the essential components of MDS sit outside the database, much like other services like SSIS are more than just a database.

Data Quality Services is a similar story: it uses three databases ([link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/data-quality-services/install-windows/install-data-quality-services?view=sql-server-ver15)) and seemingly some components outside the databases, so wouldn't be possible to deploy in standalone Azure SQL DBs. It may be possible to run on a Managed Instance, I couldn't find a clear answer to that. And again, there is no fully-serverless offering at this time.

Of course, all of this can easily be run via IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service) using an Azure virtual machine running SQL Server.